# Laravel Socialite Saml2: Ideal Location for SAML Config XML file

Tags: php, laravel, saml, saml-2.0, laravel-socialite

I was implementing the Saml2 using Laravel with an Identity provider metadata XML file by following the documentation on [this page](https://socialiteproviders.com/Saml2/#installation-basic-usage).

I have added the following code:

```
'saml2' => [
  'metadata' => file_get_contents('/path/to/metadata/xml'),
],
```

Now, I wanted to understand the most recommended way to store this XML file in the Laravel folder structure.

I should definitely not be putting it in the Public directory since it will be publically accessible and anyone can download it.

I can not put it in the Storage directory too since Storage Directory is ignored by git.

I was wondering, what is the ideal location to save this file so that I can access it in the  `config/services.php` and is maintained in Git.

Reference Link I am referring to:

- Laravel Socialite: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite
- Socialite Providers Doc: https://socialiteproviders.com/
- Socialite Saml2 Service Provider Doc: https://socialiteproviders.com/Saml2/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you want to add SAML metadata XML files to your version control software? I prefer to think of these files as user-generated data rather than source code, and would treat them similarly to database records that are backed up and restored. In my implementation I extract the key values from the XML records and put them into a database table so I may fetch them as needed.

In your case, you wish to store each SAML metadata XML file as a text document in a directory. If your application consists of a single server instance you can put the files in Laravel's local storage/app directory. If, however, your application consists of multiple deployments then you will need a shared storage area that each instance may access. A networked file server or caching service could act as a central repository for these files. Amazon's S3 service or a Redis cluster are good examples.